# How to apply filter for pivot table through combo box in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

In Pivot Table `Facility` field there are 9 different facilities and how to select a particular facility through Combo Box(Using Excel 2007).

Below is the code i have tried but it is selecting all 9 facilities.

```
        .PivotFields("ProjectCode ").Orientation = xlRowField

        With .PivotFields("Facility ") = ComboBox1.Text
        '   .PivotItems("ABC ").Visible = True
        '   .PivotItems("DLF ").Visible = False
        '   .PivotItems("EON ").Visible = False
        '   .PivotItems("XYZ ").Visible = False
        '   .PivotItems("SEZ ").Visible = False
        '   .PivotItems("QAZ ").Visible = False
        '   .PivotItems("QWE ").Visible = False
        '   .PivotItems("RMZ ").Visible = False
        '   .PivotItems("POI ").Visible = False

        End With

        .PivotFields("Facility ").Orientation = xlColumnField`
```

ComBox1 source data is selected from named range in sheet1.

[image]

It is giving required result for all 9 facility,
Now how to make a pivot table that takes value from ComboBox?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work. It will run when the command button is clicked.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Facility").PivotFields("Facility ")
        .PivotItems(ComboBox1.Text).Visible = True
        For Each Item In .PivotItems
            If Item.Value <> ComboBox1.Text Then
                Item.Visible = False
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```